# ubuntu 16 not accepting the login password

Tags: 16.04, password, update-manager

In the beginning I had set a password to login into the system, then I removed it because every-time when the screen used to blackout, I had to type the password.

Now, I can't open synaptic package manger.  It asks for the password, if I type the password it does not accept it, if I do not type anything and just click "authenticate" still it does not let me in.

I had to do this as there is a red color circular icon on top right corner, it says "An error ocurred, please run package manger...."

when I click on "install all updates" it says "package system is broken"

How can I install all updates and why package manger is not accepting the password, I am logged in as Admin.

Comment: How did you remove the password?

Comment: @danzel, system settings > user accounts

Comment: So you activated the "Automatic Login" option? If so, your user password shouldn't have changed. Please try entering `sudo echo` into a terminal ([Ctrl]+[Alt]+[T]) and see if your password is accepted.

Comment: @danzel, tried, it does not accept, says "sorry..."

Comment: You can [reset your password](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/354663) and see if that helps.